# Kerberos authentication not running when client and server on same machine

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego

I am getting the following error when trying to trying to access the application from the same machine where jboss server is running

```
  org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesfull       at     org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:69)        at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:120)         at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: G
SSHeader did not find the right tag)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at   org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJ
```

Is there any way to get it working when both client and server are on the same enter code here machine? I am using IE9 on Win7 and how to confirm that the token is NTLM rather than kerberos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE and all browsers using SSPI send by default a NTLM token in this case.

See [Are the client and server on the same box?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2009/12/31/things-to-check-when-kerberos-authentication-fails-using-iis-ie.aspx). The issue is described in [MS's knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-us) with possible solutions.

Comment: its for intranet applications and unfortunately only IE is used, is there any way to bypass the authentication?

Comment: Nothing what I am aware of. Maybe someone else knows better.

Comment: I am trying in Firefox and getting 401 error, I am trying to do a kerberos authentication. It works fine when invoked from a Java Test class, so it has got to do with some browser setting? how can I configure browser to do a kerberose authentication

Comment: You have to enable it, `about:config` > `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` and `network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris`.

Comment: thanks Michael, did the changes, Firefox is now trying to authenticate but getting the same error as in IE Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag) , is there other browser setting to get it working for localhost/machine name where the Jboss AS is running locally?

Comment: Did you supply the FQDN or `localhost`. I think this is a [limitation in SSPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/01/02/cannot-generate-sspi-context-error-message-poisoned-dns.aspx). This means that every client who's using SSPI suffers from this.

Comment: Please check forward and reverse DNS entries.

Comment: thanks, looks alright. did nslookup IPaddress and nslookup abc.mycompany.com both results are same, is that what you were looking to test?

Comment: Yes, entries are fine. See my edit. It might solve your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot, looks interesting article, will go through them and try few things.

Comment: Welcome! Please report your results.

Comment: after changing the 'Custom Settings' in IE (select the option to prompt for username & password option) I don't get the error, but gets a prompt to enter username and password, this at least allows me to carry on development on my local machine and test even though it is not exactly the same way it works when the web server is on a remote machine. thanks.

Comment: Did you disable the loopback?

Comment: no, I have asked the Windows admin guys to do that, will let you know once i can test with that option.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am not able to figure out from where the jboss server gets the default kdc and other configurations when krb5.conf is not specified in Linux environment. I have deployed a spring application and specified the 'krbConfLocation' property but left the file as blank. The application still authenticates the user and logs the user in, I would have thought that as the server wont find the kdc location it would fail, do you know from where it gets the default values?

Comment: If you are on Java 7, JGSS does as Windows does, it checks DNS SRV records for the next available KDC.

Comment: hi, @java1977
did you find anyway to call server from client on the same machine ?

Comment: unfortunately no, I think security feature feature prevents the authentication when on same machine. I had to use basic authentication when running the application locally.

Comment: @java1977 Did you try to set the reg key to disable this behavior?

Comment: that worked but I had to revert it due to security policy.

Comment: The links are dead.